# Java Async Invoke in method Waiting on Return

Tags: java, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I know there are probably a couple ways to do this, just looking for the most efficient and concise way to go about it:

```
public Object giveMeNewObject() {
    final Object result = null;
    SomeApiClient.start(new Callback() { // starts an async process
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object somethingNew) {
            result = somethingNew; //ERROR; can't set cause final
        }
    });
    return result; //result is null, cause Async already finished
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Why do you start an asynchronous process if you want to return the computed value? The caller will need to wait either way. It sounds like you want to return a `Future` of the value, the caller doing what it wants with it?

Comment: result must be declared final to use inside the Callback object; so how do I set the result?

Comment: I do want a Future object; but the issue isn't just getting the main thread to wait, but also getting the result from inside the callback that has no return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code - this is modified on fly so correct mistakes and all will work as you expect - caller will wait untill 3rd party finishes the processing and will get the result of that process:

```
public Object giveMeNewObject() {
    CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);
    Callback callback=new Callback() { 
      public sometype result=null;
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object somethingNew) {
            result = somethingNew; //ERROR; can't set cause final
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    SomeApiClient.start(callback);
    latch.await(sometimetowait);
    return callback.result;

}
```

Comment: What a question and what an ANSWER.. The real sulution I was seaching for...

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Your job should be done in `doInBackground` method and the result should be returned by that method. Later on you can use `get(Timeout)` method to retrieve that returned value. `get` will even block if the computation in `doInBackground` is not complete yet for given ammount of the time.

You can find tons of examples of how to use async task. One of them is in the API documentation (link above)

Comment: so my question to this is; I will be starting an async call inside and async task, what is my async's task; to wait for result to no longer be null? Still have the issue of, how do I set result (declaring a field outside an object sets its modifier to final)

Comment: So we have main thread, AsyncTask1 - T1, and AsyncTask - T2.
Main starts T1, T2 starts T2. What should be the outcome? Is T1 Terminating after starting T2? Should T1 wait for T2 to finish? Should MainThread wait for T1 to finish?

Comment: the AsyncProcess is what i'm waiting on to complete; but it has a callback when it finishes, so really what I'm waiting on is on the callback to finish. So how do I tell my T1 to wait on the result from the callback?

T1 starts T2, T1 waits on T2 (but T2 finishes instantly cause it has a callback)

Comment: If your background task invokes another background task and waits for it to finish - this is just a bad design. This is can be done by single thread. In your case you are using 2 threads from pool to do one job. Insteed of using callbacks just read the link I have gave you and use `get` method to await background task completion. It sounds like you are using `AsyncTask` in the way it was NOT ment to be used. Read the API docs for that

Comment: okay; maybe I'm not explaining very clearly. 
The AsyncProcess object is from some API i don't have control over; it allows me to pass a callback object and it does some async operation and returns the result to that callback object, meanwhile, my code returns a null result.

So this means I need to wait for the result object to be set to something other than null, right? Easy enough, I just set it equal to what is in the callback, but, you can't do that, cause the result object must be set as FINAL to be used inside another class (the callback class)

Comment: @nuebKitsune TL;DR you better edit your question as what you are asking for is definetly not what you have described. And yes, you are way to unclear.

Comment: @nuebKitsune but for the sake of clarity. Use `CountDownLatch` in the callback. You will pass that latch to the callback so it will count down when your taks finishes. Meanwhile your main thread should call `CountDownLatch.await` - this way your main thread will block untill callback is called by the async task. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: Insteed of final variable, use either field or store the reference to your callback, make it store the result value and later on access that value.

Comment: that sounds like a concise and efficient solution to me; thanks :)